# Trouble instantiating class and adding it to an array - object properties are always 0?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Why is `coords` always `0,0` no matter what I put for the values in `let $newTileData = new tile([1,3],{})`?

```js
class tile {
    constructor(coords, layers) {
        this.coords = [0, 0];
        this.layers =
        [
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            //player "layer" is here?
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""}
        ]
    }
}


let mapdata = {
    mapName: "Test",
    tiles: [    ]
};

let $newTileData = new tile([1,3],{})
mapdata.tiles.push($newTileData);
console.log(mapdata);
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the parameters `coords` and `layers` in your `constructor`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Maybe in an answer? Maybe with an example?  Maybe on a train? In a plane?

Comment: Did you mean to write `constructor(coords, layers) { this.coords = coords; this.layers = layers; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a constructor that actually uses the constructor parameters rather than only setting default values. If the default values are necessary to keep in place (to maintain the working empty constructor `new tile()`), code can be added to accommodate that.

```
// this would need to be used with values, new title([0,0], {layerdata})
class tile {
    constructor(coords, layers) {
        this.coords = coords;
        this.layers = layers;
    }
}
```

Comment: aaaaaah.  Not only the correct answer, but it was actually posted AS an answer.  Bonus explanation and no snark!

Answer (score 1):

`coords` is always 0,0 no matter what you put for the values because you declare:
`this.coords = [0, 0];` in the class. You are ignoring the input value when you do that. Same as ignoring `layers`:

```
this.layers =
        [
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            //player "layer" is here?
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""},
            {sprite: ""}
        ]
//Now the function(layers) doesn't do anything because layers is ignored.
```

Comment: So is there no such thing as like a class "structure"? Like, is there even any point to making it a class? Seems like no. Note that I have never used classes in JS and I'm not a programmer by trade...

Comment: Seems I may as well just do `mapdata.tiles.push{[1,3],{layerdata})`

Comment: @JOATMON: You can create objects directly. There is no need for a class to just store data.

Comment: I guess where it may be more useful is if I'm not defining the layer data at instantiation (which I won't be), so keeping that part will save me some time.

Comment: "*You are overwriting the input value when you do that.*" - no, not even that. The input is simply ignored, the variable introduced by the parameter is completely separate.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, thanks for telling me that, I keep learning more everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what I had in mind... Thanks to @quicVO for leading me to this.

```
let $newTileCoords = [1,3];
let $newTileData = new tile()
$newTileData.coords = $newTileCoords;
mapdata.tiles.push($newTileData);
```

Will leave unanswered in case someone comes up with a more appropriate way to instantiate a class with values.